# Passing 'props' to children component and conditionally render it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-props

It's my `loginButton` which is the wrapper of `Button` component in another file.

```
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useTransition } from 'react';

interface LoginButtonProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  mode?: 'modal' | 'redirect';
  asChild?: boolean;
}

export const LoginButton = ({
  children,
  mode = 'redirect',
  asChild,
}: LoginButtonProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const onclickHandler = () => {
    router.push('/auth/login');
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  return (
    <span className="cursor-pointer" onClick={onclickHandler}>
      {children}
    </span>
  );
};
```

and the `Button` component is:

```
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { LoginButton } from '@/components/auth/login-button';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
        <LoginButton>
          <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" className="mt-8">
            Sign in
          </Button>
        </LoginButton>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I want to pass the `isPending` state as prop and use inside `Home` component. I want to keep the button disabled while `isPending` is true as well as change its text. how to achieve this?

Please help me with your valuable time and knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try passing a *fallback* component to the `LoginButton` that will be rendered while the **transition** is pending.

**Login Button:**

```js
export const LoginButton = ({
  children,
  mode = 'redirect',
  asChild,
  fallback
}: LoginButtonProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const onclickHandler = () => {
    router.push('/auth/login');
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  return (
    <span className="cursor-pointer" onClick={onclickHandler}>
      {isPending ? fallback : children}
    </span>
  );
};
```

**Fallback Component:**

```js
function LoadingBtn() {
 return (
   <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" className="mt-8" disabled>
      Loading
   </Button>
 )
}
```

**Implementation:**

```js
<LoginButton fallback={<LoadingBtn />}>
          <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" className="mt-8">
            Sign in
          </Button>
</LoginButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And I solved the problem. But I wanted to implement this in another way, like using ```React.cloneElement```.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function (instead of a react element) as children of `LoginButton`

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
        <LoginButton>
          {disabled => ( 
            <Button 
              variant="secondary" 
              size="lg" 
              className="mt-8" 
              disabled={disabled}
            >
              Sign in
            </Button>
          )}
        </LoginButton>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

and call this function in `LoginButton` component

```
export const LoginButton = ({children}) => {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  ...  

  return (
    <span className="cursor-pointer" onClick={onclickHandler}>
      {children(isPending)}
    </span>
  );
};
```